# Override HttpContext.Current.Cache in Load Balanced Envrionment.

Tags: asp.net, caching, redis

We have an environment with a vendor deployed application to several front ends on it.  It makes heavy use of the ASP .Net storage (Session, Application, and Cache).  Problem is with the load this environment quickly brings IIS to it's knees with the amount of data it's trying to keep in memory.

The solution we are trying to go with is to override the storage mechanism and implement our own. (Specifically a Redis server to manage the storage)

We have implemented their cache interface and set up `Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider` in the web.config to manage the session.  That part all works fine.  The problem is that the caching inside the vendor application does not always use their provided interface.  Decompiling the dll and examining dump files show that there are several instances of them directly calling (for example):
`HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert(...)` and `HttpContext.Current.Application[...] = ...`

Is there any way we can override the HTTPContext* calls so that they'll use Redis to cache instead of the Asp .Net application storage?

Answer (score 0):

When it is a "3rd" party which uses HttpContext.Current you probably have no chance to change that behavior.

Is this other application running within your context (do you control the app domain). Or is it a standalone application?
I once tried to change HttpContext.Current.Cache for unit testing and ended up mocking the whole HttpContext because it was so very internal somewhere in the Microsoft stack.

All this is pretty hard to do, not really recommended and can lead to all kinds of other errors.
In short, don't use HttpContext.Current.Cache. Use something you can inject.

In general, libraries should never use that static context.
It is much more flexible to have abstractions + DI for those kind of things...
For caching, you could use [CacheManager](http://cachemanager.michaco.net) for example.